# How to Play MP3 in Rhythm box

Tags: software-center

Got an error while downloading restricted extras.
[To install restricted extras,these items must be removed.]
 "Libav codec library; Libav utility library"
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong, `APT` needs to remove those packages to install the *extra* version of those packages which contains *more* codecs.